# Dual-gate mosfet gate resistance at DC

Tags: mosfet

I'm investigating a bf1105 dual-gate mosfet for use in an rf mixer circuit. I've never used a dg mosfet before so I decided to do a DC sweep of the gates to determine an appropriate bias point. I built the following circuit to sweep g2 with an Arduino, using PWM as a crude DAC. I can adjust the DC voltage on g1 manually via the potentiometer. The sweep range is roughly 0-4.5 volts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5zgOh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**The voltage on g2 drops by up to 20% (a volt or so) as I increase the bias on g1. Aren't the gates supposed to have very high DC resistance, like in the mega-ohm range? Why is this happening?** Could ESD or overheating the mosfet during soldering cause this? It seems to be otherwise functional.

When I replace the PWM filter with 1k resistor & 22n capacitor (i.e. similar cutoff frequency but lower impedance) the effect is no longer noticeable.

Comment: you are driving that gate with variable duty-cycle pulses of 0/5 volts

Comment: Yes. The RC filter smooths them out though. My scope shows only DC voltage at the gate (though it changes as the sweep progresses). The filter appears to do a very good job (as it should, according to the math). I can make out individual steps in the sweep as dots on the screen in X-Y mode.